# How use "arguments" object in jquery function similar as 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need use parameter `arguments` in jQuery function as my own element, not as default element.
My code:
I should call backbone superclass in `$(window).load`:

```
 MyController.__super__.scroll.apply(this, arguments);
```

I make something like this:

```
 var context = this;
 var contextArgs= arguments;
 $(window).load(
   function(){
   MyController.__super__.scroll.apply(context , contextArgs);  //call backbone superclass
 });
```

I don`t want to create new param 'context ' and 'contextArgs'. 
I can only prevent creation var context = this; by using Jquery.proxy:

```
 var contextArgs= arguments;
 $(window).load(
     $.proxy(function() {
         MyController.__super__.scroll.apply(this , contextArgs);
     },this)
 );
```

How prevent creation another param  `var contextArgs= arguments;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in other arguments to `proxy` and they'll be available as arguments in the function:

```
$(window).load(
    $.proxy(function(contextArgs){
        MyController.__super__.scroll.apply(this , contextArgs);
    },this, arguments)
);
```